# PHP load XML and check for match

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that I need to loop through and check for a string match. Not sure why the code below isn't working, i.e. does not return "true".

**XML**

```
<AUTHORIZED>
<USER>janedoe</USER>
<USER>sallysmith</USER>
<USER>walterwilliams</USER>
<USER>jennyjones</USER>
</AUTHORIZED>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $user = 'janedoe';

    //Load xml file
    if (file_exists('users.xml')) {
        $authUsers = simplexml_load_file('users.xml');
    } else {
        echo 'Could not find list of authorized users!';
    }

    //Check for approved user
    if(in_array($user, $authUsers)){
        $approvedUser = 'true';
    } else {
        $approvedUser = 'false';
    }

    echo $approvedUser;

?>
```

Comment: Please do a `var_dump` on `$approvedUser`. I don't think it is structured like you think it is.

Comment: `var_dump($approvedUser)` yields: `string(5) "false"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `simplexml_load_file` returns a `SimpleXMLElement` and not an `Array`, so you can't use the `in_array` function to do this.

What you **can** do, is take the value if `$authUsers->USER` (which is also a `SimpleXMLElement`), convert it to array, and then check it:

```
$str = "<AUTHORIZED>
<USER>janedoe</USER>
<USER>sallysmith</USER>
<USER>walterwilliams</USER>
<USER>jennyjones</USER>
</AUTHORIZED>";


$user = 'janedoe';

$authUsers = simplexml_load_string($str);
var_dump((array) $authUsers->USER);

//Check for approved user
if(in_array($user, (array) $authUsers->USER)){
    $approvedUser = 'true';
} else {
    $approvedUser = 'false';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome. A vote up for the answer will also be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry about that. Done :)